# Recreating a split screen with a sticky side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked at multiple other posts on this topic however I can't find one that replicates the feature I'm looking for exactly. What I'm trying to accomplish is something similar to the "We make scheduling for you easier than ever" section on https://calendly.com/. As you can see, when the user scrolls through, the image on the right becomes sticky once it's in the center of the right half of the screen, and as you scroll through the paragraphs on the left, the image fades into different images. I'm trying to recreate this exactly, but it's not working out at all. I've tried using js to calculate the scroll percentage and based upon that, fade the image out and the new image in, but it just doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```css
[flow], [sticky]{
  flex: 1
}

[sticky]{
  background: salmon;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

[flow]{
  height: 300vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: slateblue;
}

p{
  height: 50vh
}
```

```html
<p>content for scroll</p>
<div main>
    <div sticky>sticky part goes here</div>
    <div flow>flow part goes here</div>
</div>
<p>content for scroll</p>
```

if you want `flow` and `sticky` to start at the same level, you need negative `margin-top` equal to `sticky`'s `height` on `flow`. I used attributes to make html nicer, but use classes instead.

Comment: Try using on full screen mode. I think that's what you wanted

Comment: Do you know how I could make it so that the image would change based upon how much the user has scrolled through the flow div?

Comment: sure. take look at [this](https://codepen.io/Spoochy/pen/LYYdGgJ?editors=0010) pen. 10 lines of JavaScript. Modify it to fit your html. You're welcome.